# Microsoft’s Clarity breaks down CSS and does not upload background images

Tags: user-experience, clarity, ms-clarity

Microsoft’s Clarity breaks down CSS and does not upload background images to Heatmaps. How do I fix this so that the sessions look normal?

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzAwf.png)
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKJl1.png)

I reviewed the website through Google Page Speed and GTMetrix. These services see the site, CSS and background images normally.

Answer (score 1):

All Static data(images, Styles, CSS) should be publicly available to render in Clarity.
Please refer [Troubleshooting Recordings | Microsoft Docs for possible reasons & resolutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/session-recordings/troubleshooting-recordings) why CSS or fonts may appear broken in recordings and heatmaps.